# Question about field extensions regarding minimal polynomial of multiple of algebraic element

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $K/F$ be a field extension, let $α ∈ K$ be an algebraic element with minimal polynomial
$f(X) ∈ F[X]$, and let $r ∈ F^\times$. What is the minimal polynomial for $rα$ in terms of $r$ and $f$?

I think I am getting mixed up but I cannot see a way to do this problem without expressing the minimum polynomial for $r \alpha$ in terms of $r,f,\alpha$. I have tried rearranging it many times and has come of no avail.

Comment: I haven't thought about this much - this is my knee jerk assumption, but I think it would be $g(\cdot)=f(\cdot/r)$

Comment: @Dom: I basically agree. Perhaps one should rewrite it to be monic by multiplying by $r^{\operatorname{deg}(f)}$ so that $g(X)=r^{\operatorname{deg}(f)}f(Xr^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now having thought a little more, we can see that the minimal polynomial must be $g(\cdot)=f(\frac{\cdot}r)$ as clearly $g$ has $r\alpha$ as a root and if it weren't the minimal polynomial then $f$ would not be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (essentially by the same trick done the other way on any lower degree minimal polynomial of $r\alpha$).